# Make half the code async, but keep the old code sync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, web, async-await

I currently am tasked with implementing some new functionality into an API that will eventually replace the existing code once everything (images) are transferred to the new system.

I have a controller which is currently not async

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(long imageId)
{
  //Old sync code
  var imageStream = GetImage(imageId);

  var response = Request.CreateResponse();

  response.Content = new StreamContent(imageStream );
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
  return response;
}
```

There is of course a bunch of synchronous calls to the DB and different resources already in this method.

If I made this method async and returned before the synchronous code in the new code, will the old code still function that same way and just be executed synchronously?

For example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetImage(long imageId)
{
  Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
  var newImage = await IsNewImage(imageId);

  if (newImage)
  {
   //Do async work
   imageStream = await GetNewImage(imageId);
  }
  else 
  {
   //Old sync code
   imageStream = GetImage(imageId);
  }

  var response = Request.CreateResponse();

  response.Content = new StreamContent(imageStream);
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
  return response;
}
```

The reason for this is to try to minimize touching the old code that will be going away, and implementing the new code async. I just want to make sure introducing async functionality into this is not going to change the existing sync code? I do not have the option to create new controllers, it has to be changes to the existing controller in this instance.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: What is the `newImage` flag? Why not replace the call to `GetImage` with `GetImageAsync` (the async versio)? Why/when would `newImage` ever be `false` once you added your functionality?

Comment: Edited the post to indicate where newImage is coming from. I am keeping the 1 controller so I don't have to change every application referencing this controller as they are hardcode get URLs essentially

Comment: Why not `var imageStream = await GetNewImage(imageId) ?? GetImage(imageId);` Have the new method return `null` if it is not a new image, get rid of the `IsNewImage` call.

Comment: @Servy, the code runs find, I just don't know if I am suddenly going to hide erorrs or anything in the old sync code that I am not expecting

Comment: @Igor, sure that works, this is just a POC, this is not the real code but good call to simplify it.

Comment: Also when creating methods that return `Task` or `Task<T>` it is considered best practice to append the suffix Async to the method name. So that would be `GetNewImageAsync` instead of `GetNewImage`.

Comment: @mameesh If you want to know what happens when an exception is thrown in either of those methods, then intentionally throw an exception and see what happens, and whether that exception is handled properly.

Comment: It seems to be fine for all intensive purposes, though I am wondering if there is anything blatantly wrong with the approach, or if the idea makes sense.